# Problems reading video file "Open CV WARNING: Couldn't read movie file bird.avi"

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

I am having huge problems working through a simple tutorial in relation to opencv using C++ in Xcode. I am unable to get the program to read the movie file. Please note the commented out sections are me testing if there is a problem unrelated to reading a container format. I.e. all the paths/ibraries etc are fine. I have tried avi containers mp4, mov etc etc- Here is the code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp> 
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


Mat frame; // Container for each frame

string video = "bird.avi";
//    string video = "hat.jpg";

VideoCapture vid(video);
if (!vid.isOpened()) { // Check if video file was opened
    cout << "ERROR: Video file not opened...\n";
    return -1;
}

// Get fps from video inputCvCapture *input_video = cvCreateFileCapture("guitarplaying.avi");
int fps = (int)vid.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS); // Gets FPS from video
cout << "FPS=" << fps << endl;

// Create a window for displaying the video
namedWindow("hello"); // Creates a window
while (1) {
    if (!vid.read(frame)) { // Check end of video file
        cout << "Video file ends.\n";
        break;
    }
    // Show the frame on window
    imshow("hello", frame); // Show current frame on window
    // Wait for read next frame or key pressed
    if (waitKey(1000/fps) >= 0)
        break;
}
return 0;



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
string video = "bird.avi";
```

with the full path, for example:

```
string video = "c:\\samples\\bird.avi";
```